# Updating salary of employees when their salary is less than a threshold kept

Tags: plsql

I have this problem, I want to update salary of employees whose salary is less than 0.5 of managers salary using plsql procedure, it compiles but when ever I try to exec the code it doesn't work. any idea what the problem might be? maybe from the code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INC_SALARY(PRC NUMBER)
  IS
BEGIN
  LOOP
    UPDATE EMP 
    SET SALARY = SALARY * PRC
    WHERE EMP_ID IN(
    SELECT E.EMP_ID
     FROM EMP E
     JOIN EMP M
     ON E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMP_ID
     WHERE E.SALARY < M.SALARY * 0.5 );
  END LOOP;
END INC_SALARY;

EXEC INC_SALARY(1.20);
```

Comment: 1. What is the `LOOP` for? In such construction, your code should execute infinitely - see [INFINITE LOOP concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop). 2. Are you sure you want to update employees whose salary is less than 0.5 of their managers' salary, not some average or median salary of all managers?

Comment: Yes, i want to update the salary of employees whose salary is less than half of their managers salary.  the loop is to fetch all employees

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer in the comment, you completely misunderstood what an `UPDATE` statement does - check here [UPDATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php).
One `UPDATE` statement is enough to meet your requirements.
`LOOP` is never needed in such scenario, unless you wanted to fetch every single record (using `SELECT` statement) and execute an `UPDATE` one by one (also known as `slow by slow`).

To see how many employees gets updated with your one `UPDATE` statement, you can execute your query used in `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` statement:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(E.EMP_ID)
FROM EMP E
JOIN EMP M
ON E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMP_ID
WHERE E.SALARY < M.SALARY * 0.5
```

I added a few comments to your code to explain to you, what your code actually does:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INC_SALARY(PRC NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    -- Enter the loop and start executing the code into the loop
    -- over and over again
    LOOP
        -- Update EVERY employee whose salary is less than
        -- a half of the salary of his manager
        -- setting his salary to his salary multiplied by PRC parameter
        UPDATE EMP 
        SET SALARY = SALARY * PRC
        WHERE EMP_ID IN(
            SELECT E.EMP_ID
            FROM EMP E
            JOIN EMP M
            ON E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMP_ID
            WHERE E.SALARY < M.SALARY * 0.5 
        );
        -- Update finished - loop starts another iteration
        -- and calls Update for EVERY employee over and over again

        -- Since there's no exit from the loop 
        -- (loop never ends, iterates infinitely)
        -- the execution never ends
  END LOOP;
END INC_SALARY;
```

Comment: What i really want to do is to fetch every employee whose salary is less than half of their manager's salary and update their salary just once. so in this case i don't need loop?

Comment: Exactly. Your `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statmenet actually does the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion whenever possible try to use SQL rather using PLSQL. In this case I can see this can be done via single UPDATE query. If any specific reason for Procedure then go for it otherwise try to use simple UPDATE

```
UPDATE EMP 
        SET SALARY = SALARY * PRC
        WHERE EMP_ID IN(
            SELECT E.EMP_ID
            FROM EMP E
            JOIN EMP M
            ON E.MANAGER_ID = M.EMP_ID
            WHERE E.SALARY < M.SALARY * 0.5 
        );
```